# Compiling LineageOS 17.1 generates only system.img but no zip package?

Tags: android, lineageos

Like the Title says, i can't figure out why it's not generating a flashable zip package with updater-script and so on.

Some years ago when i was compiling CM11 this worked fine.

**Solution:**
Thanks @dcow for the hint !

i was using

```
lunch dreamlte
```

instead

```
brunch dreamlte
```

btw: `make -jx bacon`
works as well where x is the number of threads or cpu cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done this in a few years either, but I'm pretty sure you now directly flash images using fastboot, not janky recovery image adb sideload update zips...

Edit:

Looks like Lineage still has people sideloading zips and only uses fastboot for the recovery partition. If you `brunch`ed and don't see a zip in `$OUT` I would assume your build wasn't actually successful.

Comment: So generating a usual recovery package is like deprecated ?
I still need/prefer to have classic file-based update.zip package.

Comment: Deprecated might be a strong term. If you download factory nexus/pixel images from google the software is installed by a script running on your host machine that makes various `fastboot` calls, not via an `adb sideload` package update script running on the target mobile device. The sideload strategy must just be a lingering ecosystem familiarity thing.

Comment: Ohh ... in fact i was using "lunch" command instead "brunch".
After i've changed this in my build.sh the android-build-system was trying to generate the needed zip package but it ended up with an error. So probably i'll need now to rebuild from scratch using make clobber/clean first ?

Comment: Probably. Getting the AOSP to build initially can be a bit tricky. You might want to ask another question about the error you're getting if it's tripping you up.